# ¿Como puedo conectarme a la base de datos?

Tags: php

```php
<?php
    class Connection
    {
        private $server;
        private $user;
        private $pass;
        private $database;
        private $conexion;
        
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->setConect();
            $this->conect();
        }
        
        private function setConect()
        {
            require("datos.php");//esta parte solo cuando la necesite 
            $this->server="localhost";
            $this->user="root";
            $this->pass="";
            $this->database="alquivehiculos";
        }
        
        private function conect()
        {
            $this->conexion = @mysqli_connect($this->server, $this->user, $this->pass);
            if($this->conexion)
            {
                mysqli_select_db($this->conexion, $this->database);
            }
            else
            {
                error_log(0, "error de conexion");
                exit("intente mas tarde");
            }
        }
        
        public function execute($query)
        {
            $ejecucion=mysqli_query($query, $this->conexion);
            $result=array();
            if(mysqli_errno() == 0)
            {
                while($row=@mysqli_fetch_row($ejecucion))
                {
                    array_push($result, $row);
                }
                return $result;
            }
            else
            {
                echo mysqli_error();
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.SO], recuerda revisar [ask] y hacer el [tour]... cual es el error que te muestra?

Comment: Si ya estás trabajando con clases, ¿por qué usas el estilo procedual de mysqli? Usa el estilo [orientado a objetos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples).

Answer (score 1):

te dejo una forma de hacerlo:
archivo `config.php` :

```
    <?php 
$contraseña = " ";
$usuario="";
$BD=" ";
$server=" ";
try {
    $conectionBD = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;database=$BD;Encrypt=1;TrustServerCertificate=1",$usuario,$contraseña);
    $conectionBD->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Ocurrio un error al tratar de conectar con la BD Actividades: ".$e->getMessage();
}

$contraseña = " ";
$usuario = " ";
$BD = " ";
$server = " ";
try {
    $conecNuevaBD = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;database=$BD;Encrypt=1;TrustServerCertificate=1", $usuario, $contraseña);
    $conecNuevaBD->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Ocurrio un error al tratar de conectar con la BD NuevaBD: " . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

y para hacer una query `head.php`

```
<?php
    $query = $conectionBD->query("SELECT ...");
if ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $var1= $row['id'];
    $var2= $row['nombre'];
    $var3= $row['Sucursal'];
}
?>
```